# Unix find list matching directories

Tags: shell, file, command-line, directory, find

I have a rather interesting problem that I am trying to find the optimal solution for. I am creating an file autocompletion backend for Emacs. This means that I am using the linux `find` command to get files and directories.

The backend is given a file with a partially completed path (e.g. `/usr/folder/foo`) and I want to grab all files and directories that could match the partial path for two directories down (e.g. for example it could provide `foo_bar/`, `foo_bar/bar`, `foo_bar/baz`, `foo_bar/bat/` `foo_baz`). So far I have only been to break this down into 3 steps

find all files in the current directory that may match the prefix

```
find foo* -type f -maxdepth 1
```

collect all possible directories we may want to look through

```
find foo* -type d -maxdepth 1
```

use each of those directories to make 2 more calls to find (I need to be able to differentiate between files and directories)

```
find foo_bar/ -type d -maxdepth 1
find foo_bar/ -type f -maxdepth 1
```

This solution involves **a lot** of calls to `find` (especially because the last step has to be called for every matching directory). This makes getting candidates slow, especially in large file systems. Ideally I would like to only make *one* call to get all the candidates. But I have not found a good way to do that. Does anyone know an optimal solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking though the `find` manpage, I ended up using `-printf`.

```
find -L foo* -maxdepth 1 -printf '%p\t%y\n'
```

gives me everything I needed. only one command, differentiate between files and directories, search depth, etc.